# Unity3D - Issue when trying to apply ".byte" file as an object texture

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, textures

I am creating a C# script that applies an imported texture to a plane (Game Object) when the program starts. For that, I am copying the user choosen image to the assets folder. Then I change it to .byte extension, that's because I am using TextAsset to read and set the object texture.

Now what i consider that is failing is the texture Load, this is the full script code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class setplant : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject plant;
    void Start () {
        plant = GameObject.Find("plant");
        string currentdirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string pathconfig = (Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(currentdirectory, "..\\Pick_And_Build\\Launcher\\Launcher\\bin\\Debug\\tempfiles\\"))+"instanciateprogram.dat");
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(pathconfig);
        string img = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.Close();
        string textureresourcepath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Assets\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(img) + ".byte";
        if(!File.Exists(textureresourcepath))
            File.Copy(img, textureresourcepath);
        TextAsset imageasset = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(Path.GetFileName(textureresourcepath), typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(imageasset.bytes);
        plant.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
    }
    void Update () {
    }
}
```

**Note:** *The image is copied to the Assets folder so the directory system is working.*

The output for this is just a Plane with the Default-Material instead of the image texture-based material.
**Any tips?**

Comment: @JoeBlow It is Unity Engine. That is not true, in this case if you use the command `UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath()` you have to use the Assets folder wich is the main files folder.

Comment: @JoeBlow I watched some tutorials on the Internet and they use the TextAsset type to encode .jpg or .png files to .byte and then the Texture.Load(image.bytes) to encode the bytes for the texure. I supose using the image directily won't work but i'll try!

Comment: @JoeBlow can you find any soluction? I've found this but still not working: `Texture tex = (Texture)Resources.Load(filename);`

Comment: Is it just me or am I missing half of the conversation in the comments above?

Comment: ye he deleted comments

Comment: I've seen his comments around here. He can get... (let's say) passionate sometimes ^_^ All good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

It was a stupid bad extension issue. It is not .byte ... ".bytes" is the correct one. Thank you anyway for the people that tried to help me.